# nodeman looking for .meta files

Tags: node.js

I followed the instructions from:
https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Installed:

```
sudo npm install -g nodeman
```

And then i run:

```
nodeman app.js
```

and i get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodeman/docs/app.js.meta'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.help (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodeman/lib/nodeman.js:172:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodeman/bin/_nodeman:61:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

My app.js  just contains this:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead({
        'Content-Type':'/text/plain'
    });

    response.end('hello world');

}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: I uninstalled node and re-installed with brew  and i still get the same error.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

it's because it's nodemon  and not nodeman

Comment: thanks, that a dumb mistake.  didn't even notice it.  Also clears up why no one else had this issue...

Comment: It's hilarious that this is exactly the reason, lol.

Comment: i was stuck at this for days....

Comment: The man who made nodeman should be in jail. Lost hours.